# lag() to identify change in state in R is showing unexpected results

Tags: r

I am trying to apply lag function as below:

```
merged_stchg <- merged_tot %>% group_by(LanID) %>% #group observations by their id
  mutate(state = ifelse(NACH.P.F == 1 & lag(NACH.P.F) == 0, 1,0))
```

Here merged_tot(dataframe) have below structure:

```
Month LanID NACH.P.F state
    12  a1  1   0
    12  a2  1   1
    12  a3  1   0
    11  a1  1   1
    11  a2  0   0
    11  a3  1   1
    11  a4  1   0
    10  a1  0   0
    10  a2  1   0
    10  a3  0   0
```

The expectation is when NACH.P.F goes from 0 to 1 only then state must change to 1 else it must be 0.Even if there are no records prior to any record then also it must be treated as 0(as no state change from 0 to 1 observed).

I applied above code, 0's are ok(except the fact that when there is no record in prior than it gives NA(instead of 0) but thta's not primary concern here.

The problem is with 1's where i could see records with 1(either they don't have any prior entry or there are gap in months(like below month 12 after 8), so it is not working correctly.

```
Month   LanID           NACH.P.F state
12  1630516604815637      1         **1**
8   1630516604815637      1         **1**
```

I am suspecting absence of entry(NA) is being treated as 0 by the function(however NA and 0 assignments are working fine).Please suggest, what might be potential problem.

Comment: What is your expected output for the given example ?

Comment: Expected output will be values in state columns(first table) i.e when the value in NACH.P.F goes from 0 to 1 only then state columns value must change to 1 else it must be 0.Even if there are no records prior to any record then also it must be treated as 0(as no state change from 0 to 1 observed).

Comment: Can you please make this into a reproducible example? It's a lot harder to help you if we have to manufacture toy data for testing that may or may not match your specific problem.

Comment: It seems that if we use your code you are getting expected output as shown. Can you post an example of dataframe where your current code fails so that it is easier to debug.

Comment: sure, let me try if i can make it reproducible(as the dataframe is huge in size and i might not able to capture the exact scenario). Here i want to just check few things first.1) Is the code fine for given problem and i am not missing anything? 2) Do NA values contribute to the problem?

Comment: `NA` values do not contribute to the problem however, I feel you have some another condition with `Month` column which you have not mentioned. Also in the example shared you have consecutive months which doesn't represent your real data I think.